# How can I create a class method with multiple dots?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, xml-rpc

In python I want to create a (class) method with multiple dots, in order to make tests regarding `xmlrpc` methods, which can have method names with many dots. When I try just the following:

```
class Foo(object):
    def method.with.many.dots(self):
        return 42
```

I have an invalid syntax. I also tried to use more sophisticated ideas like

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print attr
```

which also does not work out-of-the-box for method names with a dot. Any ideas how I can create a simple mock object with which I can do something like

```
mock.some.test.with.many.dots()
```

in python code in a simple way, without starting a `xmlrpc` server?

Comment: Python evaluates that as the `dots` method of the `many` attribute of the `test` attribute of the `some` attribute of the `mock` object.

Comment: [HYRY's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15430170/1974792) is the one you need, but it won't work with `with` or any other keyword as in your example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr_path = []

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        self._attr_path.append(attr)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        print ".".join(self._attr_path)
        print args, kw
        del self._attr_path[:]

f = Foo()
f.a.b.c(1,2,3)
```

This output:

```
a.b.c
(1, 2, 3) {}
```

To fix @Daira Hopwood's problem:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, attr):
        self.foo = foo
        self._attr_path = [attr]

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        self._attr_path.append(attr)
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        print self
        print args, kw

    def __str__(self):
        return ".".join(self._attr_path)

class Foo(object):

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return Bar(self, attr)

f = Foo()
f.a.b.c(1,2,3)
```

To fix @Daira Hopwood's problem again:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, name=""):
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return Foo(parent=self, name=attr)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        print self
        print args, kw    

    def __str__(self):
        nodes = []
        node = self
        while node.parent:
            nodes.append(node)
            node = node.parent
        return ".".join(node.name for node in nodes[::-1])

f = Foo()
x = f.a.b
y = f.a.c
x()
y()

g = f.a
f.b
g.b.c()
```

Comment: This solution will fail if an attribute chain is accessed more than once without an intervening call. You really need multiple objects representing elements of the chain, if you want it to work robustly.

Comment: For example: When you access f.a, the _attr_path attribute of f is set to ['a']. Now suppose you access f.b (without an intervening call); then f._attr_path will be set to ['a', 'b'], which is wrong.

Comment: Note that there exist libraries, such as the 'mock' library on PyPI, that will automatically create chains of mock objects for arbitrary attributes, avoiding the above problem. (user301527's answer uses this library.)

Comment: @DairaHopwood, I modified the answer.

Comment: There are still cases where this doesn't work, although they are more obscure. For example: g = f.a; f.b; g.b.c()

Comment: @DairaHopwood, I modified the answer again, this time I use tree, I think it can solve the issues.

Comment: Yep, that'll work. For applications involving testing, though, I do recommend the mock library, which handles many other related situations.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work

Input:

```
import mock
MO = mock.Mock()
MO.some.test.wyth.many.dots.return_value = 42
MO.some.test.wyth.many.dots()
```

Output:

```
42
```

Note, "with" is a keyword.

Each dotted "descendant" is an independent (mock) object.